# How to mimic left click behaviour for right click for a TreeView in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, treeview

When I left click on a `TreeView`, it automatically selects the item under mouse. How can I do this for right click so when you right click, it also selects the item under mouse?

I want to do this because when I right click, I set the context menu of the `TreeView` when the `SelectedItem` changes, based on the `e.NewValue` of `TreeView_SelectedItemChanged`. But the right click itself doesn't change the `SelectedItem`, that's why the wrong menu shows up. Or I have to first left click to the item I want selected, and then right click.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select TreeView Node on right click before displaying ContextMenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592373/select-treeview-node-on-right-click-before-displaying-contextmenu)

Comment: Another duplicate: [In WPF, how do I select the treeview item under my cursor on right-click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797966/in-wpf-how-do-i-select-the-treeview-item-under-my-cursor-on-right-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the right click event. [Here is an example to do it](http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/NET/NETtip19.asp).

Comment: Thanks, you mean the mousedown event of the rightclick event? In the link it also shows the mousedown event.

Comment: Correct. MouseDown is how you capture the user's Right-click.

Comment: Thanks, but after that how can I perform a hittest to find the node that's clicked on?

Comment: The MouseDown event is the same for WPF and WinForms. It is a bit unfortunate that WPF removed the "GetNodeAt" function. I believe you have two options. I believe that the `sender` is actually the TreeViewItem` that you want (`sender as TreeViewItem`; check for `null`) if they clicked on one, but you can also use the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608752.aspx), which I have never used.

Comment: Thanks I found an example of VisualTreeHelper which I am using now, so I can find the node. The last bit is to set this node as selected programmatically. Do you know how to do this? This is currently what I am looking into.

Comment: Having never used it, I imagine you are looking to extract the TreeViewItem. Try `HitTestResult result = ...; TreeViewItem item = result != null ? result.VisualHit as TreeViewItem : null;` and check for `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The accpeted answer is correct about using the mouse down event, but are you sure you need Visual Tree Helper and Hit Testing? You might try something like:

```
var parent = this.DataContext as Parent;
var clicked = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Child;
parent.SelectedChild = clicked;
```

Remember, you can usually get to your viewmodel objects as the DataContext of a FrameworkElement. Using the Visual Tree and Hit Testing doesn't come up often.

Comment: Thanks, actually there are a few problems. One is I need to get the item under mouse when right clicked and so far I couldn't find a way. The other problem is selecting this item so it looks like you left clicked on it, then show my context menu.