# How do I get the item (tree node) under the mouse pointer in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#, gtktreeview

In a GTK/GTK# `TreeView`, how do I get the item/node which the mouse pointer is currently hovering over?

Comment: Use the treeview.hittest method. Just like in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750411/how-to-get-treeviewitem-using-a-coordinate-point-via-hittesting-in-wpf

Comment: @real_yggdrasil: that's for WPF, I was looking for an answer for GTK# (using Mono). I have since found the answer, but StackOverflow won't let me answer my own question for 8 hours, so I have to wait...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we want to select items using the right mouse button without using checkboxes. The following **ButtonPress** event handler does just that - it toggles the selected property of the item we have clicked with the RMB. We then use **[CellDataFunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099244/changing-the-selected-item-colour-in-a-gtk-treeview-using-python/9548415#9548415)**s to highlight the selected items. **tv** is the TreeView, **store** is the underlying ListStore.

```
[GLib.ConnectBefore]
void HandleTreeViewButtonPressEvent(object o, ButtonPressEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Event.Button != 3)
        return;

    TreePath path;
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(args.Event.X);
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(args.Event.Y);
    if (!tv.GetPathAtPos (x, y, out path)) 
        return;

    TreeIter iter;      
    if (!store.GetIter(out iter, path)) 
        return;
    Item item = (Item) store.GetValue (iter, 0);

    item.Selected = !item.Selected;
    tv.QueueDraw();
}
```

If we are using a sorted TreeView, we have to use the TreeModelSort object instead of the ListStore object to get the correct item:

```
    if (!sorted.GetIter(out iter, path)) 
        return;
    Item item = (Item) sorted.GetValue (iter, 0);
```