# How to get the position of the Expanded item in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a treeview, with multiple nested levels. For e.g., the root node of a Treeview is A, then inside A there is an item B and inside B there is another item C , like A-->B-->C. If for e.g., B is expanded in this treeview, is it possible to get the position of B in the Treeview in the code?

Comment: What do you mean by position? do you want its parent?

Comment: what I want is, I have two treeview's. Treeview A. and Treeview B. I want to expand two treeview items simultaneously. For e.g., If Treeview A has an item, "Item1" and Treeview B has an item , "Item2". When I expand "Item1", "Item2" should be expanded simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: for WPF, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437840/the-level-of-a-treeview-in-wpf) for level and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750411/how-to-get-treeviewitem-using-a-coordinate-point-via-hittesting-in-wpf) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386731/get-absolute-position-of-element-within-the-window-in-wpf) for coordinates.

The object for WPF is `TreeViewItem`

Note: below was my previous answer referring to `WinForm` `TreeView`

What you look for is `TreeNode.Level`

In your case, `TreeNode.Level` of A will return 0, B return 1, C return 2.